# Examples of Nemerle to generate c# code like T4 does

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4, nemerle

I like Nemerle's macro syntax much better than T4.  Are there any examples or is it possible to use Nemerle to generate c# code that is then used by the actual Microsoft c# compiler for input in a similar way to T4.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nemerle macros do not generate code, but rather modify the abstract syntax tree of the program as it is being compiled. However, the Nemerle compiler can read C#, and you can even use Nemerle macros in those C# files.

Comment: Yes I realize this about Nemerle but I was hoping someone knew some way of doing .ToString or something like that so I could get the C# that the macros would have expanded to.  Thanks

Comment: You could use Reflector or ILSpy to generate C# code from the compiled assembly. It would not be all that different to doing `.ToString()` on an AST.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is irrelevant but there is a Nemerle to Javascript compiler
[NemerleWeb](https://github.com/NemerleWeb/NemerleWeb)

Similar methodology can be used to generate C# files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Nemerle to C# prettyprinter is possible. But, the generated code will be ugly (not readable).

Comment: For instance given Nemerle code: match(a) { | X(Some(t)) => .. | X when someVar == 1 | _ => ... }
It creates a huge amount of code with a lot ifs an checks. 
You can try decompiling Nemerle.dll and see this.